# LSP sometimes working with Metals, sometimes spamming "the request has been cancelled"

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, lsp

I have [Spacemacs configured to use Metals](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12462) as an LSP backend for Scala development, i.e. my `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` includes:

```lisp
     (scala :variables
            scala-backend 'scala-metals
            scala-enable-eldoc t
            scala-use-unicode-arrows t
            scala-auto-start-backend t)
```

Sometimes I open a file, and everything works well. I get a rich development experience backed by whatever capabilities Metals exposes via LSP. Other times I open it up and it seems that nothing is working, and in the `*Messages*` buffer I see the likes of:

```
LSP :: Connected to [metals:38879 status:starting].
LSP :: metals:38879 initialized successfully
LSP :: The request (id: 2, method: 'textDocument/hover') has been cancelled
LSP :: The request (id: 4, method: 'textDocument/hover') has been cancelled
LSP :: The request (id: 6, method: 'textDocument/hover') has been cancelled
LSP :: The request (id: 9, method: 'textDocument/hover') has been cancelled
LSP :: The request (id: 11, method: 'textDocument/hover') has been cancelled
```

As I navigate around the Scala file, that message just spams again and again.

I'm on a Mac running Metals 0.8.0 (though this was also happening on the previous version) with Bloop 1.4.0-RC1 running as a service install installed by `brew services start scalacenter/bloop/bloop`. I've tried restarting Bloop and it doesn't fix it. I also haven't been able to figure out why it sometimes works, and other times does not.

Of course it is acceptable for requests to get occasionally cancelled, but this seems to be in some genuinely dysfunctional state. When things are working, the Scala experience in Spacemacs is good, but I would like to get that more consistently. How can I get that consistent experience?

Comment: Per [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/eorwbt/lsp_sometimes_working_with_metals_sometimes/fehki83/), submitted an [issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1323) against `lsp-mode` on GitHub.

Comment: After getting some help on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/eorwbt/lsp_sometimes_working_with_metals_sometimes/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1323), the key here seems to be looking at `.metals/metals.log`, which is [full of errors](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1323#issuecomment-575280834). That doesn't fix the problem, but it shows that it is likely not an Emacs but a Metals problem, perhaps related to [this issue](https://github.com/scalameta/metals/issues/1037). My investigation is ongoing.

Comment: Update: it seems that it works with Scala 2.12 projects, but not Scala 2.11 projects.

Comment: Same happens to me with Scala 3.0 in `build.sbt`. Going back to 2.13 fixed this. This is weird.